# Refactor nodejs module

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, commonjs

I am using Laravel Mix to compile the node modules.

In `app.js` I have following modules loaded.

```
window.Helper = require('./Helper.js');
require('./Calendar.js');
```

The `Helper.js`

```
module.exports = {
    foo: function(){
        console.log('foo called!');
    },

    bar: function () {
        console.log('bar called!');
    }
}
```

In the view I can run the functions from Helper module by simply:-

```
<script>
Helper.foo();
Helper.bar();
</script>
```

However, I could not refactor the `Calendar.js` file which runs on every pages.

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarElement = document.getElementById('calendar');
  
    var calendar = new Calendar(calendarElement, {
      plugins: [ interactionPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin ],
  
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      firstDay: 1,
      editable: false,
      droppable: false,
      allDaySlot: false,
      displayEventTime: true,
      defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:10:00',
      slotDuration: '00:10:00',
      snapDuration: '00:10:00',
      forceEventDuration: true,
      slotMinTime: '08:00:00',
      slotMaxTime: '20:00:00',
    });

    calendar.render();
});
```

How do I refactor the code so that I can load the calendar module in the same way as Helper module.

Example:-

`app.js`

```
window.Helper = require('./Helper.js');
window.Calendar = require('./Calendar.js');
```

In the view I could run like

```
<script>
    Calendar.init('#calendar');
    Calendar.run();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Helper.js`, you've specified what the module exports. In this case, you're using Node's CommonJS module syntax to specify the exported  data by assigning it to the value of `module.exports`. You can read more about this in the Node docs: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html.

In the case of `Calendar.js`, you haven't specified any exports. So when you require it, the code runs, but there's nothing being returned by that module.

In `Calendar.js`, since you're using the ES module syntax, you can specify your exports like so:

```js
export function init() {
  /* do things */
}

export function run() {
  /* do other things */
}
```

And now when you `require` it, these methods can be imported (assigned and used) in `app.js`:

```js
window.Calendar = require('./Calendar.js');
```

You can read more about ES modules here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules.